# WhiteScreen appears if the keyboard slides down in android

Tags: android, android-layout

My application is hybrid and html is injected into my webview.For instance I have a login page which contains two input boxes and a login button.When I click on the input box my keyboard pops up ,and if without closing the keyboard I click on login button the keyboard goes down but white screen appears.

I tried using

```
<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="FirstPage"android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
```

This is not showing whiteScreen but my page does not scroll.

Please help me if there is any solution to this

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should provide some code that helps identifying the problem.

Comment: My application is hybrid and html is injected into my webview.For instance I have a login page which contains two input boxes and a login button.When I click on the input box  my keyboard pops up ,and if without closing the keyboard I click on login button the keyboard goes down but white screen appears.

Below is Manifest.xml for the app
<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="FirstPage">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome the whitespace issue by giving it some time before the logging in.This gives the UI some time to resize. This is not a solution but a work around for Hybrid apps and it helped

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in menifests file like this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" then`
  this code use onclick login button to hide keyboard
this code will be work as your wish

private void login() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9.*-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9*-]+\.+[a-z]+";

```
    String sEmail, sPassword;
    EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    sEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
    sPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();
    if (sEmail.equals("") || !sEmail.matches(emailPattern)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Please enter a valid email address.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (sPassword.equals("") || sPassword.length() < 6) {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "Password must be at least 6 characters",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I can't use this because i am calling login from my javascript since my app is Hybrid App.